# Using _destroy on new objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I'm working on generating, in JavaScript, a nested form for Ruby on Rails.

Is it possible to set `_destroy` to true on a new nested object, to indicate "Don't create this an object for this, even though I've supplied attributes for it"?

I think that in gems that automate the creation of nested forms such as cocoon, the inputs are deleted instead of having `_destroy` set to true, and they only set `_destroy` to true for existing objects that the user wishes to delete. However, I'd rather avoid doing that, because it means having to handle new objects differently to existing objects.

I checked the Rails Guides to [nested forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms), but it didn't address this. I haven't tried implementing this approach, and seeing if it works, just in case it's behaviour that works but isn't fully supported.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to conditionally allow nested attributes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520710/is-it-possible-to-conditionally-allow-nested-attributes)